# C: semphore in MAC OS X unexpected sem_close error

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore

I'm trying to use semphore on my mac, and it throws me an error when I try to close an open semaphore. All initializations were successful, but when it attempted to close second semaphore, it returned bad file descriptor error.

Below code is wrapper for open and close:

```
void init_sem(sem_t * s, char * sema_name, int value)
{
    if((s = sem_open(sema_name, O_CREAT, 0644, value)) == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("init semaphore %s\n", sema_name);
}
void destroy_sem(sem_t * s, char * sema_name)
{
    printf("destroying, %s\n", sema_name);
    if (sem_close(s) == -1) {
        perror("sem_close");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (sem_unlink(sema_name) == -1) {
        perror("sem_unlink");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

and in main.c

```
sem_t * s, *a, *b;
init_sem(s, "/cs", 0);
init_sem(a, "/ps", 0);
init_sem(b, "/bs", 0);
destroy_sem(s, "/cs");
destroy_sem(a, "/ps"); //got error here
destroy_sem(b, "/bs");
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in `*s` where it becomes a local variable. When you assign a value to it, the value goes away when `init_sem` returns. Then when you call `destroy_sim`, you are passing in an uninitialized value to `sem_close`.

You need to return the value that gets returned from `sem_open`:

```
sem_t * init_sem(char * sema_name, int value)
{
    sem_t * s;
    if((s = sem_open(sema_name, O_CREAT, 0644, value)) == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("init semaphore %s\n", sema_name);
    return s;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
s = init_sem("/cs", 0);
a = init_sem("/ps", 0);
b = init_sem("/bs", 0);
```

Comment: oh btw, why compiler complains about assignment pointer from integer when I use this function..even though they have same type

Answer (score 0):

Gabe's answer is correct.

As an alternative, you can do this:

```
void init_sem(sem_t ** s, char * sema_name, int value)
{
    if((*s = sem_open(sema_name, O_CREAT, 0644, value)) == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        perror("sem_open");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("init semaphore %s\n", sema_name);
}
void destroy_sem(sem_t * s, char * sema_name)
{
    printf("destroying, %s\n", sema_name);
    if (sem_close(s) == -1) {
        perror("sem_close");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (sem_unlink(sema_name) == -1) {
        perror("sem_unlink");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    sem_t * s, *a, *b;
    init_sem(&s, "/cs", 0);
    init_sem(&a, "/ps", 0);
    init_sem(&b, "/bs", 0);
    destroy_sem(s, "/cs");
    destroy_sem(a, "/ps");
    destroy_sem(b, "/bs");
}
```